# can I get a legend for OpenStreetMap in OL3?

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, legend, openlayers-3

I have a piece of code for a web app. I need to add a legend for my base layer in OpenStreetMap.

Is it possible to have a legend for the OSM source? Because, according to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139008/openlayers-3-get-legend-not-working) and [this](http://webmappingtutorial.blogspot.hu/2014/12/controls-and-projections-in-openlayers.html), I need to get URL and Params which do not exist for OSM in  OpenLayers 3 (at least for now).

How about using a WMS layer for OSM? does that do the trick?